# How to initialize or configure a singleton/factory method in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have following factory method which I would like to initialize in spring XML.

```
public final class ProductDaoFactory {

    private static final ProductDaoFactory INSTANCE = new ProductDaoFactory();

    //so cannot new an intance
    private ProductDaoFactory() {
    }

    //singleton
    public static ProductDaoFactory getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    //factory method
    public ProductDao getProductDao(String daoType) {
        ProductDao productDao = null;

        if ("jdbc".equalsIgnoreCase(daoType)) {
            productDao = new ProductDaoJdbcImpl();
        } else if ("ibatis".equalsIgnoreCase(daoType)) {
            productDao = new ProductDaoIBatisImpl();
        } else if ("hibernate".equalsIgnoreCase(daoType)) {
            productDao = new ProductDaoHibernateImpl();
        }

        return productDao;
    }
}
```

Is the following correct way to configure it?

```
<bean id="productDaoFactory" class="com.ministore.dao.factory.ProductDaoFactory" factory-method="getInstance"></bean>  
<bean id="productDaoFactory" class="com.ministore.dao.factory.ProductDaoFactory" factory-method="getProductDao">
    <property name="daoType" value="jdbc" />
</bean>
```

Comment: -- You can check this link, http://www.javabeat.net/create-spring-beans-using-factory-methods/ in our project we use it similar way which shown at previous link.

Comment: @erhun - I tried after looking into the tutorial you mentioned and now I am getting some different exception. Do I have to write a new post for this or can I modify the existing one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following bean configurations.

```
<bean id="productDaoFactory" class="com.ministore.dao.factory.ProductDaoFactory" factory-method="getInstance"/>

    <bean id="jdbcProductDao" factory-bean="productDaoFactory" factory-method="getProductDao">
        <constructor-arg value="jdbc"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateProductDao" factory-bean="productDaoFactory" factory-method="getProductDao">
        <constructor-arg value="hibernate"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="iBatisProductDao" factory-bean="productDaoFactory" factory-method="getProductDao">
        <constructor-arg value="ibatis"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I do not have a constructor in my factory class

Comment: That is true. But that constructor-arg will be passed to the getProductDao(...) method. I think that is what you wanted. I tested with 4.2.3 and it works.

Comment: I mean, although it says constructor-arg, in your case it will be passed as parameter to getProductDao(...) method.

Comment: Ok, so shouldn't the id `jdbcDaoFactory` be actually `productDao` because we are already calling the `getProductDao()` method ? I am sure you can name it as you want but am I thinking it correctly ?

Comment: You are right. Better name would be `productDao` or even better would be `jdbcProductDao`. I hope that the suggested bean configuration worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) I would have never been able to figure out that `constructor-arg` should be used in this scenario.

Comment: Glad that worked. Marking it as correct answer would help others as well.